# mocking call to soap web service using sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, sinon

I've got a Node application using the Express application and want to mock the calls to the soap web services so that I can write some unit tests.  For mocking, i'm using [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) and [Soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) for sending requests to the SOAP web services but finding it difficult on how to approach this.

```
 before(function(done) {
   var soapWs = require('../../methods/soapWs');
   soapWs.user = soap.createClient(path + '/restsoapproxy/test/specs/testjson/user.wsdl);
   // following returns undefined
   sinon.stub(SoapWs.user, 'sessionLogin', function(err) {
      err.code = '404';
      err.message = 'error';
      // e.g. "for user not found"
      return err;
    });
   }
```

The SOAP web service has a method called sessionLogin that takes a username and email but 
not sure how to use sinon to mock a call to the soap web service - the code snippet above returns 'undefined'